# Xamarin, setting up Async DB

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

i have the following code for the interface in xamarin.

```
public interface ISQLiteDb
    {

        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();


    }
```

then if i go to Android in my DB folder i have this

```
   var documentsPath = 
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "shopItems.db3");

        return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
```

in IOS its pretty much the same
The problem that i'm having is that i  cant seem to be able to setup a table that i can use.
 As you can see im trying to setup Async DB, i know that for sync one you need to do this

```
 static SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection database;


    //creates the database itself
    public DBFunc()
    {
        database = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(DependencyService.Get<ISQLitePlatform>(),
        DependencyService.Get<SqlSync.IFileHelper>().GetLocalPath("shopItems.db3"));
        database.CreateTable<ShopItems>();


    }
```

So the question that i got confused with is how can i setup the same table with async methods? How can i the path where it should be located and how can i connect to it when i need to get data from there?

Comment: have you tried the CreateTableAsync example shown in the docs?  https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL#asynchronous-api

Comment: but will need to define any paths or anything in Droid or Ios explicitly? or i can just go and create them

Comment: that's what IFileHelper is for - it provide the path to the db that it used when you create SQLiteConnection